# Warcraft 3 Hamachi crashes ingame sometimes

Tags: hamachi, warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne

recently I started to play warcraft 3 (version: 1.26.0.6401, tft, the original) again. Since playing alone is pretty boring I made a Hamachi server and connected with my friends. Now we have the problem, that most of the times the game crashes for some people (not always the same player). So its pretty unplayable right now. What I don´t understand, that I played with one friend for ~90 minute on one map and it didnt crashed. Sometime it crashed after a minute sometimes after 40 minutes.

Anyone knows how to fix this? If more information is needed I can add it. Kinda strange problem but maybe someone ran through it.

Comment: Does it always crash? or only certain maps? are it mod maps or basic RTS maps? How good is the internet connection between all parties involved?

Comment: Internetconnection is good. I think we play ownly mod maps. I kinda asked myself if there are specific versions of a map to match games version, but couldnt find more information about it

Comment: Versions don't matter when it comes to maps. Aslong as you both have the same version. It's hard to tell what causes the problem without more details.

Comment: hm it kinda always comes if we play more than 2 player. 2 player works fine. 3 crashes with nearly 100% chance

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the connection to the internet was through 2 routers which seemed to have produced some errors